# Reading EXIF data From picute callback or imaged picked from android Gallery

Tags: android, metadata, android-camera, exif

I have a custom camera activity in my application. I want to extract EXIF data from picture callback or android image gallery. I have to read flowing EXIF data fields:

MAKE

MODEL

FOCAL_LENGTH

Those three EXIFfields should be outputted in another activity's method:

```
public void selectImageFromGallery() {
    Intent galleryIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
            android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
    startActivityForResult(galleryIntent, ACTIVITY_SELECT_IMAGE);
}

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        if (requestCode == CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST) {
            Log.e("unitycamera",
                    "cccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc");

            try {

                Bitmap thumbnail = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");

                ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

                thumbnail.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 50, stream);

                File file = new File(
                        Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                                + File.separator + "Android"
                                + File.separator + "data" + File.separator
                                + context.getPackageName() + File.separator
                                + "files" + File.separator + "image.jpg");

                Log.e("pa",
                        file.getPath() + "  :  " + file.getAbsolutePath());
                Log.e("len", stream.size() + "");
                file.createNewFile();
                FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
                outputStream.write(stream.toByteArray());
                outputStream.close();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else if (requestCode == ACTIVITY_SELECT_IMAGE) {
            Log.e("unityGallery",
                    "cccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc");

            try {

                Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
                String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };

                Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
                        filePathColumn, null, null, null);
                cursor.moveToFirst();

                int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
                String filePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
                cursor.close();

                Bitmap thumbnail = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath);

                ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

                thumbnail.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 50, stream);

                File file = new File(
                        Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                                + File.separator + "Android"
                                + File.separator + "data" + File.separator
                                + context.getPackageName() + File.separator
                                + "files" + File.separator + "image.jpg");

                Log.e("pa",
                        file.getPath() + "  :  " + file.getAbsolutePath());
                Log.e("len", stream.size() + "");

                file.createNewFile();

                FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);

                outputStream.write(stream.toByteArray());

                outputStream.close();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        Log.e("1 imagePickerStatus", Constant.imagePickerStatus + "");

        Constant.imagePickerStatus = 1;

        Log.e("1 imagePickerStatus", Constant.imagePickerStatus + "");
    } else {
        Log.e("0 imagePickerStatus", Constant.imagePickerStatus + "");

        Constant.imagePickerStatus = 0;

        Log.e("0 imagePickerStatus", Constant.imagePickerStatus + "");
    }

}
```

Here is my picture callback method:

```
PictureCallback mPicture = new PictureCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {

        Log.e("Camrera", "22222222222222222");
        BitmapFactory.Options bfo = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        bfo.inDither = false;
        // bfo.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        bfo.inPurgeable = true;
        bfo.inTempStorage = new byte[16 * 1024];

        Intent intent = new Intent(context, PreviewActivity.class);
        // intent.putExtra("data", data);
        Bitmap bitmapPicture = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0,
                data.length, bfo);
        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
        if (Constant.result == 180) {
            matrix.postRotate(270);
        }
        if (Constant.result == 270) {
            matrix.postRotate(180);
        }
        int height = bitmapPicture.getHeight();
        int width = bitmapPicture.getWidth();
        //Bitmap scaledBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmapPicture,
                //height, width, true);
        Bitmap rotatedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmapPicture, 0, 0,
                bitmapPicture.getWidth(), bitmapPicture.getHeight(), matrix,
                true);
        ByteArrayOutputStream blob = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        Log.e("Camrera1", "22222222222222222");
        rotatedBitmap.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG,
                50 /* ignored for PNG */, blob);
        byte[] bitmapdata = blob.toByteArray();
        Constant.imageData = bitmapdata;
        Log.e("Camrera2", "22222222222222222");
        startActivity(intent);

    }
};
```

Help me plz.

Comment: Is there anyone who can help me??????

Comment: @Mohmmad Rajob I'm facing same issue, did u find any solution?